# How to start a Minecraft Server from a PHP-Script

Tags: php, apache2, exec, screen, minecraft

I tried to start a Minecraft Server from my PHP-Script. It should be run in a Screen. Is there any option to do this? I tried it with `exec` / `shell_exec` and `system` but it would not work.

Can someone give me an example?

Comment: How do you start your server without php?

Comment: With the java -jar command.